# foreach loop insert $id of list items

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, foreach

I try to develop a simple comment system. The foreach row `$result` contains variables from a database named posts.

The id of the post(every post is a list item) that is AUTO_INCREMENT and every post have a unique $id, the author of the post and the comment become submitted to a file that insert the three values into a database named comments.

The second foreach loop, `$comments`, should show the comments when the user click the popup button. That does not works because the id `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />` wont become right inserted(comments.php should do that).

The result is that all comments become showed in every list item and not the only these comments who are e.g. at list item 2. How can I insert the $id of the list items into the database?

```
<div data-role="content">
    <?php include( "list.php"); ?>
    <div data-demo-html="true">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

            <?php foreach ($result as $key=> $row): ?>

            <li id="listone" name="listone" data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child">
                <?php echo $row[ 'date']; ?>
            </li>
            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a">
                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit">
                            <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong></strong>
                                <?php echo $row[ 'time']; ?>
                            </p>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong>
                            </p>
                            <p class="ui-li-desc">
                                <?php echo $row[ 'text']; ?>
                            </p>

                            <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['town']; ?></strong>
                            </p>
                            <a href="#popupcomment" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">comment</a>
                            <div data-role="popup" id="popupcomment" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
                                <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <?php include( "showcomments.php"); ?>
                                        <?php foreach ($comments as $keyComment=> $rowComment): ?>
                                        <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $rowComment['username']; ?></strong>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="ui-li-desc">
                                            <?php echo $rowComment[ 'comment']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>" type="text" />
                                        <!-- autor des posts -->
                                        <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a" />
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </a>
            </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- div content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

> showcomments.php:

```
$hostname='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';

$id = $row['id'];
try {
     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood",$user,$password);

     $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
     $sql = "SELECT id, username, comment, time 
             FROM comments 
             WHERE  id_post = $id 
             ORDER BY id DESC"; 
     // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
     if ($com = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
      // then after fetchColumn
     $comments = $com->fetchAll();       
     }                        
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> comments.php:

```
$hostname='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';

if(isset($_POST["id"])){                    
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        // prepare your query
        $query = 'INSERT INTO comments 
                    (username, autorpost, comment, id_post, time) 
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now())';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        // bind variables
        $stmt->execute(array($_COOKIE['username'], $_POST['autorpost'], $_POST['text'], $_POST['id']));
        // pull last insert id
        $new = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 

        // show success message or redirect, whatever you want
        echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
        $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lendsth/main.php", true, 302);

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to make a column in your database that stores which comment is posted under which "id_post"  -- Ideally, you'd create a table for the posts and a table for the comments. That, or if you aren't storing the posts in a db, each post is going to need to have a unique identifier of some sort that you store with each comment.

Your table would be set up as such:
First Table -> Stores the "posts" that will have comments

Table - Posts:
post_id, post_content

Table - Comments:
comment_id, comment_content, post_id  (This is the ID of the post that the user posted under -- You could store this in the hidden post_id input, and pass it along using POST to the form processing.

Your select would look like this

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '{your post id}'
```

I don't know if this will help but might lead you down the right path.

Comment: Mh thanks for you attention but the insert of the id in comments.php fail. The inserted values are all the same. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. You need to give the post an ID to store with the comments

Comment: The post have already a id which becomes AUTO_INCREMENTed by mysql

Comment: You are misunderstanding what I am telling you. Unless all the comments are going to be on the same page, each "page" or "post" needs to have a unique ID. Then that ID needs to be stored with the "comments"